# Update mysql table using data from json file

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am complete new to json and thefore struggling to work with.

I have a list of id's stored in a id field of a mysql table.

For example id field contains these values

1. 100001
2. 100002
3. 100003

The json file containes properties of these id's, like this.

```
{"100001":{"person":{"name":"John","age":"32,"address":"123 street"}},
{"100002":{"person":{"name":"jenny","age":"22,"address":"100 street"}},
{"100003":{"person":{"name":"james","age":"25,"address":"200 street"}}
```

My intention is to update the name, age and address fields in the mysql table with the data in json file using the id as a conditon in the where clause.

But I have no idea where to even start.

Can someone who know's what they doing, please direct me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what you struggling to understand? json_decode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$var = '{"100001":{"person":{"name":"John","age":"32,"address":"123 street"}},
{"100002":{"person":{"name":"jenny","age":"22,"address":"100 street"}},
{"100003":{"person":{"name":"james","age":"25,"address":"200 street"}}';

print_r(json_decode($var));
```

that will give you an array you can either foreach though and create separate update statements of build one large update statement and execute it.

Comment: Hi thanks for yor quick reply. I understand json decode. I am just not able to apply it to this particular data structre. Also I don't how to combine it with update statement. I have tried your suggestion and I just get blank screen, no errors or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD be getting an error somewhere; your curly braces don't match and you're missing closing quotes after the age:

```
{"100001":{"person":{"name":"John","age":"32,"address":"123 street"}},
```

should be

```
{"100001":{"person":{"name":"John","age":"32","address":"123 street"}}},
```

You're missing the closing brace for the actual ID. To make it easier to read, try formatting like this:

```
{
 "100001":{
           "person":{
                     "name":"John",
                     "age":"32",
                     "address":"123 street"
                     }
           }
 },
```

Comment: Thanks for that EmmyS. Should have seen the age quote. However the json file am working with does not have a closing bracing for each entry. instead it has a comma separting each entry. The closing bracing only appears on last entry to indicate the end of the file.

Comment: Then there shouldn't be an opening brace before each ID number, there should only be one before the first. You can't have mismatched braces.